# Windows 7: Incorrect Registry Files

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, windows-registry

## Issue Summary

I messed up a couple values in my Windows Registry, I know which ones, I am having a hard time changing them back.

## Issue

I was trying to change the default location for program installations. I found out I could do this in `Regedit` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion` and I started to change every value in there which start with `D:` instead of `C:`

This led to an error popping up when I try to launch programs (like Regedit) that states:

> "Windows cannot find 'C:\Windows\regedit.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."

You can replace `C:\Windows\regedit.exe` with pretty much everything I try to run on the computer right now.

## Attempted Solutions

1. I attempted to dive into the C: drive and run regedit from my Windows folder. No dice there
2. I attempted to run cmd (success) and run the REG command from there (no success), since it asked for the admin password (there is none).
3. I attempted to run the REG command and put in a blank admin password, error-ed out, saying admin password cannot be blank (approximately)
4. I attempted to run a new cmd from cmd as an account with admin privileges, and it says I did not have privileges

## Question

Does anyone know a way I can fix this short of re-installing? (I do not have a disc, purchased the computer from a friend of a friend) I am not sure where the registry binary file/files are located, but I would like to dive through them since I can check my working computer to see what the code should looks like for the files I changed.

Comment: Did you try a system restore already? A system restore should to my knowledge include registry values. (at least system values)

Answer (score 0):

On the small chance that it works: run RegEdit on the PC which does work, and choose menu option "File > Connect Network Registry". Then pick your broken PC. With a bit of luck, remote registry access is still working.